# Entity Framework 6: Trim does not work properly

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I have a process which should copy data from one database entity to another. Therefore I use **Entity Framework 6** and **LINQ** expressions in **C#**:

```
public partial class ReferenceEntities : DbContext {
     public Nullable<System.DateTime> ActivationDate { get; set; }

     public string Code { get; set; }
}

this.ReferenceEntities.ReferenceEntity.AsEnumerable().Select(referenceEntry => new StagingReferenceLoader() {
    ActivationDate = referenceEntry.ActivationDate,
    Code = referenceEntry.Code?.TrimStart('0').Trim()
});

this.ProcessingEntities.StagingReferenceLoader.AddRange(stagingEntries);
this.ProcessingEntities.SaveChanges();
```

`Code` is `char(11)` column in both entities which are affected by this process.

Example:

In **StagingReferenceLoader** the `Code` value looks like this: `00000253089`

With the **Trim** operations I want to make it look like this: `253089`. This looks fine on the first way, when I have executed it. 
But if I ran this SQL query on the database directly it gives my the result as following:

```
SELECT DATALENGTH(code), len(code), code
FROM staging.ReferenceLoader

datalength | len | code
11         | 6   | 253177     
11         | 6   | 270724
```

Why does Entity Framework just does not do the **trim** operation?

Comment: Could you change [Code] to a varchar(11)? I think the problem is that char(11) always has a fixed length.

Comment: I will try it. Thanks

Comment: @CarlosAdrián It works. Thank you very much

Comment: I have copied the comment as an answer, please check it as valid answer, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of Code field must be varchar(11), because char(11) has a fixed length. The DB so will always fill it to the full length. Please, change it to varchar.